# How to uplift values to siblings in React js

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to print addition of two number using React JS

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <InputNumbers />
      <PrintAddition />
    </div>
  );
}
```

App Contains two components PrintAddition & InputNumbers, Where InputNumbers components take values from inputs and that data has to be sent to it sibiling component PrintAddition, How ?

```
function PrintAddition() {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>
        The addition of numbers is <span>{Here result has to be printed }</span>
      </p>
    </div>
  );
}

function InputNumbers() {
  const [num1, setnum1] = useState(0);
  const [num2, setnum2] = useState(0);

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        className="num1"
        type={"text"}
        onChange={(e) => setnum1(e.target.value)}
      ></input>
      <input
        className="num2"
        type={"text"}
        onChange={(e) => setnum2(e.target.value)}
      ></input>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: See any basic react turorial e.g. https://react.dev/learn/sharing-state-between-components

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move state to the App component and use props to pass them into specific components.

```
function App() {
  const [num1, setnum1] = useState(0);
  const [num2, setnum2] = useState(0);
  return (
    <div>
      <InputNumbers setnum1={setnum1} setnum2={setnum2} />
      <PrintAddition num1={num1} num2={num2} />
   </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways of doing this. One of the easiest is to let `App` hold the state and send it to `PrintAddition`.

You'll need to send the `setter` funciton to `InputNumbers` so they can call it in the `onChange`.

Another option would be to use something like React Redux to save that data in a Store.

---

Demo based on OP"s code:

```js
const { useState } = React;

const Example = () => {

    const [input, setInput] = useState([]);
    
    const setter = (index, value) => {
        setInput(p => {
            let n = [ ...p ]
            n[index] = value;
            return n;
        });
    }
    
    return (
        <div>
            <InputNumbers setter={setter} />
            <PrintAddition sum={input.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)} />
        </div>
    );
}

function PrintAddition({ sum }) {
    return (<p>The addition of numbers is <span>{sum}</span></p>);
}

function InputNumbers({ setter }) {
    return (
        <div>
            <input className="num1" type={"text"} onChange={(e) => setter(0, +e.target.value)}></input>
            <input className="num2" type={"text"} onChange={(e) => setter(1, +e.target.value)}></input>
        </div>
    );
}
ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```